# specify include directory only for specific source files with gcc

Tags: gcc, include

I am wondering if it is possible to specify include directories to gcc such that only specific source files check that directory.  What I mean is, I want a command line like this:

```
gcc -I[File1 Include Dir] [File1].c -I[File2 Include Dir] [File2].c
```

such that the #includes in [File2].c will NOT search [File1 Include Dir] but only [File2 Include Dir].

[File1 Include Dir] and [File2 Include Dir] will contain files and directories with the same names which is why it is important that [File2] not begin looking for files in [File1 Include Dir] because it would find a file with the name it was searching for, but it will be the wrong file.

The restrictions are I cannot change the code in the source files to use absolute paths, and I must get the desired behavior in just one command line.  Also, I cannot just give two commands in one line with something like &&.  What is really happening is I must gather all the arguments to pass to a script which invokes gcc; I cannot invoke gcc myself.

Is such a scenario possible?

Comment: Why are you forced into this scenario?  It would be much easier to just use two gcc calls.

Comment: I know, but for the purposes of this question, such are my restrictions.  If the described scenario is not possible then the "script" which takes the arguments will have to be modified to remove the restriction.

Comment: The whole question is making absurd requirements on you.  Without a clear motivation for really dealing with the issues (not just artificial constraints imposed by a sadistic professor or TA), the correct answer is "that is not a sane way of trying to do the compilations".

Comment: Agreed.  But the motivation is if such a thing is possible, the existing build system need not be changed.  So I really just want to see if the above is possible or not.  If its not, that's fine.  Just wanted to see if anyone could confirm that.  The lack of answers may be my answer.